Yocto Mickldore Group RT Scheduling issues with pthread created with FIFO policy
I'm currently building a yocto image using 6.1-mickledore (mickledore).
When I run my application it exits prematurely because of some pthread_create code. It looks like when I comment out setting the policy to FIFO the program runs fine. After a bunch of internet searching I found out this was because of group rt scheduling. The program is able to run if I disable the group rt scheduling using the command sysctl -w kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us=-1 described in this link here
Although I have a solution during runtime I don't quite understand how to reconfigure to yocto to disable this by default. Does anyone know how to disable this group rt scheduling in the bitbake recipes?

How hard this can be? Just add it to /etc/sysctl.conf !

The solution to this problem can be found here:
Add New Kernel Parameter To Custom Linux Image Generated By Yocto
Essentially running sysctl -w kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us=-1 set's the /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us
This can be defaulted by appending a default value in /etc/sysctl.conf. For example kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = -1
To configure this in yocto, we can create a procps folder, procps_%.bbappend and systctl.conf in recipes-extended in your layer such as
meta-my-layer/recipes-extended/
└── procps
    ├── files
    │   └── sysctl.conf
    └── procps_%.bbappend

procps_%.bbappend:
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
